# Where is maven in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have Eclipse Juno with M2E plugin. I use eclim and I want to build my apps from terminal. I cannot find maven executable to add it to path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't anywhere. M2E embeds Maven, it doesn't install it. You need to install it for yourself.